# Spaces between stars (*) in hidden password are not uniform

Tags: flutter, flutter-textinputfield

Any idea why the spaces between the stars in the hidden passwords are not uniform? Is it doing some kind of grouping? Any thoughts on how to make it uniform?

[image]

Here is the code snippet,

```
TextField(
          key: const ValueKey('text_field'),
          enableInteractiveSelection: widget.enableInteractiveSelection,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          obscuringCharacter: widget.obscuringCharacter ?? '•',
          controller: _textEditingController,
          inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatter,
          keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
          obscureText: widget.obscureText ? _hidePassword : false,
          maxLength: widget.maxLength,
          maxLengthEnforcement:
              MaxLengthEnforcement.truncateAfterCompositionEnds,
          autocorrect: widget.autocorrect,
          enableSuggestions: widget.enableSuggestions,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
)
```

Comment: Can you add the code which you are using to create that field ?

Comment: @MidhunMP added the code snippets

Comment: @TapasPal How you defined that input formatter ?

Comment: It is null in this case.